# How to show combo box values to textbox with next line

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have one ComboBox in which there are multiple values are selected I want to show that values in TexBox with next line like

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Currently its show in one line

```
AAA | BBB | CCC
```

I use bellow code

`DataCardValue4.Selected.Value` on Default Property of TextBox

Comment: Are you using text label or text input control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula for `Default` property of text input in this format:

```
Concat(ComboBox1.SelectedItems, ThisRecord.Value1, Char(10))
```

Where `ComboBox1` is the name of combo box control.

**Output**:

[image]

You may need to adjust the formula slightly as per the data source you used in `items` of your combo box control.

Comment: I am using textbox control this form is in View mode values are coming from gallery selected item. So I use above code 'Concat(DataCardValue4.SelectedItems, ThisRecord.Value, Char(10))' But still its shows in same line

Comment: If you are using **Text Input** control, set it's mode property to `MultiLine` text input.